# How to find path of file in MAUI for all platforms?

Tags: c#, maui

I'm making an app that I want to export to both Windows and Android. In this piece of code, I'm trying to read from a .csv file:

```
using (StreamReader csv =  new StreamReader("MOCK_EMPLOYEE_DATA.csv"))
```

However, It keeps giving me an error that the file was not found and the path was incorrect. What is the best way to go about this?

The file is in my project folder.

[image]

Comment: how did the file get there in the first place?  Did you write it on the fly?  If so, use the path you wrote with to read it back.  If it is part of the app bundle, then there is a different method to read it.

Comment: Where do you expect the .csv file to be?

Comment: @ewerspej the file is in the project folder

Comment: You have to bundle the file, you can’t just drop it in the project tree.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android

Comment: @Jason that doesnt teach how to bundle files

Comment: It sort of does, but it's indeed not so obvious. You need to set the Build Action of the file to `MauiAsset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by following these steps:

1.Drag or add the csv file to the Project.

2.Set the Build Action of csv file to **MauiAsset**.

3.use the following code to read the file:

```
using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("File.csv");
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(contents);
```

Hope it works for you.